# elFinder file manager preventing image popup on double click

Tags: javascript, file-manager, elfinder

I have a question about elfinder file manager. When I double click on an image, I want to prevent opening it on Windows.

Can someone help me please

I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid opening image or any kind of file on mouse double click, you must add getFileCallback() - callback to the elFinder options object. Inside you can get file url as it shown inside the example below.

```
 $('#elfinder').elfinder({
    getFileCallback: (file, fm) => {
       let fileURL = file.url;

       $('#elfinder').remove();
    },  
 })
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include an explanation of why this is the answer.